# What happened to all the questions on Meta?

Tags: bug, meta, question-lists, homepage

I don't see any questions on Meta on any of the tabs (but the suggested questions that come up based on the title still seems to work). I am able to view questions via direct links, and search works, but the actual lists are MIA.

[image]

Comment: Please refresh 1-2 times

Comment: That's a common bug I think on all stack exchange sites. Refreshing the page, as hims056 has suggested, does eventually solve the issue.

Comment: This happens occasionally, probably some cache-related issue. It usually resolves itself within a minute or less.

Comment: It happened to me right now: I only saw one question (this one) which was reported to be "a question with new activity." Once I refreshed the page, I saw the other questions as well.

Comment: @Haidro not very common, I hope... if it is, I hope we'd hear about it

Comment: @hims056 I refreshed several times, and also checked all of the question tabs.

Comment: @MarcGravell Happened to me yesterday on MSO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A build glitched. Specifically, we have a small group of nodes that run the question lists; in a disaster every web-server is also capable of running that code in-process, but we centralise it normally. As we were deploying that cluster, it went a little wrong leaving no nodes. It would have self-recovered (running locally), but I have repaired the cluster.

Comment: I've experienced that in the last few days, though, a refresh normally fixed it. Has this issue been dragged along a couple of days?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I've been doing a lot of work on that cluster over the last few days...

Comment: I see, that explains that.