# Super User not showing any questions

Tags: bug

A couple of minutes ago I went to take a look at Super User but when I got on the page there were no questions displayed on the homepage. When I checked the questions tab it was also "empty". I tried to refresh the page a couple of times but still nothing happened. After about a minute I got the questions back on the homepage but still not in the questions tab. A couple seconds after that the questions also came back to the questions tab. 2 days ago I had also had this problem on Stack Overflow but the questions came back there in a couple of seconds. Also when I was on Super User when the questions were gone I got the `1 question with new activity` message and when I clicked on that it was still only displaying that single question. I think this is a bug or does anyone have an explanation on this?

[image]

Comment: I see that someone beat me with the same question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177169/218170) with a couple of mins..

Comment: Ya It was on StackOverflow too, kinda a maintenance glitch but it's fine now